# How should one respond after each plague is named during the seder?

Tags: minhag, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, passover-seder-hagada, plagues-makkos

In the Haggadah, the Ten Plagues are recited, and a drop of wine is spilled for each one.  However, in the Tunisian tradition (and maybe others), after the reader chants each plague, the others respond with something.  What do they say?  It happens starting at 16:13 in this video of Nathan Cohen's recitation of the Haggadah:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDEKagDAT_I&t=972

I'm guessing Tunisian Jews aren't the only ones who say this, and it may be a response to generally hearing about bad things, I don't know.  That's why I'm asking!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:74wL1e2YPb4J:qjsi.bhol.co.il/ArticlePrint.aspx%3Fid%3D67022%20&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk) cached page:

> בשעת אמירת "עשרת המכות" שופך הגר"מ יין לתוך קערה, והמסובים מכריזים "**ה' יצילנו**" על כל מכה ומכה

After every one of the 10 plagues, after spilling out some wine the communal response is ***Hashem Yatzilenu* - may Hashem guard over us.**

Comment: Nice.  I should add that, in the Tunisian video posted in the question, it sounds like they are saying **HaShem MaTzileinu - HaShem *guards* over us.**